# Construction of an initial algebra from a weakly initial algebra

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to understand the following construction of an initial algebra from a weakly initial algebra (see [here](https://www21.in.tum.de/%7Etraytel/mscthesis.pdf), section 4.5)

Let $\mathcal{A} = (A,s)$ be an algebra.

Let $M_s$ be the intersection of all sets $B$ such that $(B,s)$ is an algebra.

Let $M(\mathcal{A})$ be the minimal subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$, then:

> Statement 1: $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}) = (M_s,s)$
>
> Statement 2: there exists at most one morphism from $M(\mathcal{A})$ to any other algebra...
>
> Statement 3: given a weakly initial algebra $\mathcal{C}$, the desired initial algebra is its minimal subalgebra $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{C})$

I'm not understanding the construction well. How should I define minimal subalgebra? Why should that be equal to the **intersection subalgebra** $M_s$ with the same structure mapping?

I hope someone can clarify me these notions. I don't see this construction in the literature.

**Update:**

Section 7 of [this paper](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/trayteld/papers/itp14-card/card.pdf) seems to provide a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can infer from the passage in the text

"Given an algebra $\mathcal{A}=(A,s)$, let $M_s$ be the intersection of all
sets $B$ such that $(B,s)$ is an algebra and let $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$,
the *minimal subalgebra* of $\mathcal{A}$, be $(M_s,s)$."

the minimal algebra $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ is defined via this construction.

Observe that, since $(A,s)$ itself is an algebra, the set $A$ belongs to the collection of those sets that are used for the intersection, so one might as well restrict the intersection to all *subsets* of $A$.

A mathematician would probably just have written

"Given an algebra $\mathcal{A}=(A,s)$, let $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})=(M_s,s)$ be the intersection of all subalgebras of $\mathcal{A}$"

but computer scientist sometimes prefer it a bit more convoluted."

Comment: what really confuses me is, is it necessary that subalgebras have the same structure morphism $s$?

Comment: It should be the 'same' structure map, up to a bit of sloppy language: in general an homomorphism $u: (B,t) \to (A,s)$ between two algebras is a map $u: B \to A$ such that $s\circ u = u \circ t$.  For a subalgebra we usually take $u$ to be the inclusion $B \hookrightarrow A$ and then the above conditions forces $t$ to be the restriction of $s$ to $B$ together with $s(B)\subseteq B$. Hence the simplified notation $(B,s)$ .

Comment: They claim that this notion corresponds to that of subalgebra generated by the empty set. How would you understand this?

Comment: That makes sense. Observe that subalgebras are closed under intersection, so for a given subset $U$ of an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ we can consider the intersection of all subalgebras that contain $U$. This is the smallest subalgebra that contains $U$ and is commonly called the subalgebra generated by $U$. The special case $U=\emptyset$ will give the minimal subalgebra.

Comment: Actually it should be $s \circ u = F(u) \circ t$ right? this poses the question on why there exists at most one morphism from the minimal algebra to any other algebra

Comment: Yes, I forgot the $F$ from the structure maps $t: F(B) \to B$ and $s: F(A) \to A$ so the condition should be

 $u \circ t = s \circ F(u)$.

I do not expect that minimal algebra to be initial. After all it is only minimal among the subalgebras of a given Algebra.